# Relationship between clang, opt, llc and llvm-linker

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I looked at the source code of clang, llc, and opt a little while ago, to see how each one of them adds optimizations to the pipeline. My understanding was that clang adds the same optimizations that opt and llc have in their pipelines, by calling the same methods that opt and llc call. Also clang does not separately call opt and/or llc.

This is almost fine, except that there is a risk that at some point opt may end up with different optimizations in its pipeline (when compared with clang) due to source changes that is done in one but not the other. Same is true for the comparison of llc and clang. Is this perception correct?

Also I have seen charts that show the following workflow: clang, opt, llvm-linker, opt again (for IPA?) then llc. I cannot connect this workflow to what I have seen in the clang. Even my understanding of LTO is that the linker (Say gold) will call optimizations. I cannot understand the role of llvm-linker here.

Any insights is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

opt, llc and llvm-linker are developer-side tools that could be used to run some methods implemented in LLVM libraries. End-user normally should never use them.

The "charts" are probably just someones' custom-built quick'n'dirty LTO pipeline.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give more comments on what is the point of llvm-linker? My biggest question is that it is equivalent of system linker?

Comment: Another question: Do you think that there is a risk that optimizations in opt and clang go out of sync because a code change made on one of them is not reflected in another?

Comment: It depends. There's llvm-link which is to link bitcode files together and lld which is an attempt to replace the system linkers similar to how clang replaces system compilers.

Comment: And no, not typically because the optimizations in opt are generally part of an O1/O2/O3 framework and so not called explicitly. Also the same people implementing the passes will make sure they're called from within clang.